# List all Storage Accounts and containers in Aure w/Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I am a novice at Powershell. I have been tasked with listing all storage accounts, along with all the underlying containers, for one of our Azure subscriptions. So I looked to see if a script existed, but couldn't find one. I then set about heavily modifying one that was originally for something different. Figured it would be a good learning exercise.

So what I am wanting my script to do is to work through the subscription, spit out all the storage accounts, and then go through each storage account to list all the containers within them. There are dozens of accounts to go through, each with multiple containers. Once done, throw it into a formatted CSV.

So far I can get the script to output the storage accounts, but nothing more than that. I am running this on my own test environment before hitting the live one, just in case.

Hoping that someone can throw some pointers as to what I'm doing wrong.

Script as below:

```
##################################################
# Gather storage account information 
#     across all subscriptions
##################################################

Write-Host "Gathering storage account information...`n"

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$saUsage = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList

# Loop through each subscription
foreach ($subscriptionId in $SubscriptionIDs) {

# Set context to the subscription
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionID | Out-Null
$context = Get-AzContext
Write-Host "The subscription context is set to: $($context.Name)`n"
$storageAccounts = Get-AzResource -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts' 
$containers = Get-AzResource -ResourceType 
'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers'
}
# Check the account can access storage accounts within the subscription
if (!$storageAccounts) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Account '$($context.Account.Id)' does not have access to any 
storage accounts in subscription '$($context.Name)'"
    $storageAccounts | Format-Table StorageAccountName, ResourceGroupName, Location
    continue
}

Write-Host "Progress Status:"
[int]$i = 1
```

## Loop through each storage account and gather usage information

```
    foreach ($storageAccount in $storageAccounts) {

        Write-Host "[$i of $($storageAccounts.Count)] $($storageAccount.Name)"
        $i++
```

## Gather storage account details and store as a PS custom object

```
            $StorageAccountDetails = [ordered]@{
                SubscriptionName = $context.Subscription.Name
                SubscrpitionID = $context.Subscription.Id
                StorageAccountName = $storageAccount.Name
                ContainerName = $container.containerName
                ResourceGroup = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName
                Location = $storageAccount.Location
        }
        $saUsage.add((New-Object psobject -Property $StorageAccountDetails)) | Out-Null
    }
    foreach($container in $storageAccount.BlobContainersOperationsExtensions.get) {
        if($container.containerName) {
   
# Gather storage account container details  and store as a PS custom object

        $StorageAccountDetails = [ordered]@{
            SubscriptionName = $context.Subscription.Name
            SubscrpitionID = $context.Subscription.Id
            StorageAccountName = $storageAccount.Name
            ContainerName = $container.containerName
            ResourceGroup = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName
            Location = $storageAccount.Location
        }
}

        $saUsage.add((New-Object psobject -Property $StorageAccountDetails)) | Out-Null
    
} 

# Output storage account usage results to .CSV
if($saUsage) {
# Output to CSV
$saUsage | Export-Csv -Path $SAOutputPath -NoTypeInformation
Write-Output "`nExported storage account usage report at $SAOutputPath`n"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following script

```
$context = Get-AzContext

$storageAccounts = Get-AzResource -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts' 

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$saUsage = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList

 foreach ($storageAccount in $storageAccounts) {

   #list containers
   $conatiners= Get-AzRmStorageContainer -ResourceGroupName $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName -StorageAccountName $storageAccount.Name

     if($conatiners -ne $null){
          foreach($container in $conatiners){
            $StorageAccountDetails = [ordered]@{
                    SubscriptionName = $context.Subscription.Name
                    SubscrpitionID = $context.Subscription.Id
                    StorageAccountName = $storageAccount.Name
                    ContainerName = $container.Name
                    ResourceGroup = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName
                    Location = $storageAccount.Location
               }
             $saUsage.add((New-Object psobject -Property $StorageAccountDetails))  | Out-Null   
            }     
      }else{
      
        $StorageAccountDetails = [ordered]@{
                SubscriptionName = $context.Subscription.Name
                SubscrpitionID = $context.Subscription.Id
                StorageAccountName = $storageAccount.Name
                ContainerName = $null
                ResourceGroup = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName
                Location = $storageAccount.Location      
         }
        $saUsage.add((New-Object psobject -Property $StorageAccountDetails)) | Out-Null
     }     
}
$saUsage | Export-Csv -Path e:\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for that! Script is now working perfectly. I started trying to mess around with dynamic variables as I was using the get-AzStorageContainer module, but had real problems trying to call the variables as a context for each storage account.